# Error when configuring session state server

Tags: asp.net, session-state, appfabric, session-state-server

We have 4 machines behind a firewall and hardware load balancer.

We are trying to setup session state server. When we do, we get the following error:

> Message: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 210.18.207.181:80 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)

Note the IP address in the error message is the IP of the load balancer, but when we do a trace between the servers it does not go via the load balancer. The NLB stands in front of the servers (between them and internet), and the servers are all on the same LAN/subnet.

The session state service is started. and the web.config contains the following:

```
<sessionState
     mode="StateServer" 
     stateConnectionString="tcpip=xxx.yyy.zzz.www:42424"
/>
```

Where xxx.yyy.zzz.www is the ip address of one of the servers behind NLB. All servers communicate with each other on the same LAN/subnet with nothing between them. Despite this the exception (above) contains the IP of the load balancer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why you are using public IP of the machine for state server, why don't you use private IP{Lan/local IP} of the machine?

Comment: What does the state server portion of web.config look like?

Answer (score 0):

in regedit set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state \Parameters

AllowRemoteConnection = 1
```